# Adding a space within a line in file with a specific pattern

Tags: replace

I have a file with some data as follows:

795 0.16254624E+01-0.40318151E-03 0.45064186E+04

I want to add a space before the third number using search and replace as

795 0.16254624E+01 -0.40318151E-03 0.45064186E+04

The regular expression for the search is \d - \d. But what should I write in replace, so that I could get the above output. I have over 4000 of similar lines above and cannot do it manually. Also, can I do it in python, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could findall to get your matches and then use join with a whitespace to return a string where your values separated by a whitespace.

[`[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+E[+-]\d+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/PXxqki/2)

```
import re
regex = r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+E[+-]\d+)?\b"
test_str = "795 0.16254624E+01-0.40318151E-03 0.45064186E+04"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(" ".join(matches))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HFU91675)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it very easily in MS Excel.

1. copy the content of your file into new excel sheet, in one column
2. select the complete column and from the data ribbon select Text to column
3. a wizard dialog will appear, select fixed width , then next.
4. click just on the location where you want to add the new space to tell excel to just split the text after this location into new column and click next
5. select each column header and in the column data format select text to keep all formatting and click finish
6. you can then copy all the new column or or export it to new text file